# What cookies are allowed from Internet Explorer using this option?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

When I look at the options used from Internet Explorer for the cookies, I read the following description:

> Blocca i cookie di terze party privi di una versione compatta dell'informativa sulla privacy.

> [image: screenshot]

The screenshot has been taken from Internet Explorer 9, but that sentence was used also in previous versions. This is the screenshot for the English version.

> [image: screenshot]

The sentence that isn't clear to me is *Blocks third-party cookies that don't have a compact privacy policy.*

From that description, it seems the cookies should include a compact description of the privacy informative, but I don't get how cookies can contain that information, or what happens with cookies set from sites outside the European Union.

What cookies are exactly blocked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual English text is:

> Blocks third-party cookies that do not have a compact privacy policy.

This means that all cookies from third-party sites (ie. other than the site you're currently visiting) will be blocked unless the site can present a valid [P3P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P) privacy policy.

From [techliberation.com](https://techliberation.com/2009/03/06/privacy-solutions-series-part-3-internet-explorer-privacy-features/):

> A P3P compact privacy policy is a machine-readable summary of the full P3P specification, which is a standardized method for explaining a website’s privacy policy.

This privacy policy isn't contained in the cookie itself, but instead is served by the web server, either as a separate file or a specially formatted HTTP header (see [this MSDN article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120420161817/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537341(v=VS.85).aspx) for more in-depth information and examples). The browser will need to know to look for this information before saving a cookie, and currently Internet Explorer is the only major browser supporting P3P.